# Checkbox is checked by default

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm starting to learn vue js .

I have a checkbox :

```
<input type="checkbox" value="users" class="pull-right" v-model="user.permissions">
<input type="checkbox" value="edit user" v-model="user.permissions">
<input type="checkbox" value="add user" v-model="user.permissions">
```

That is putting a data on `user.permissions` whenever I  check the checkbox.

```
user:{
    permissions: []
},
```

Is there a way where i can check the specific checkbox by default? I tried to bind `:checked="isTrue"` but nothing is happened.

this one should be default checked

```
<input type="checkbox" value="users" class="pull-right" v-model="user.permissions">
```

Comment: use `permissions: true`

Comment: the problem is i have some different checkboxes that is using the user.permissions as v-model

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `users` as a first element of your `user.permissions` array.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    user: {
      permissions: ['users']
    },
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="checkbox" value="users" class="pull-right" v-model="user.permissions">
  <input type="checkbox" value="edit user" v-model="user.permissions">
  <input type="checkbox" value="add user" v-model="user.permissions">
</div>
```